# NoReadAccessException exception while exporting Lint errors to generate HTML Report in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, lint

I want to export html report of Android Lint Errors and Warnings in Android Studio(used by - Android studio -> Analyze - Inspect Code).

But when I click on export icon on the left, i get following exception:

**NoReadAccessException**

```
        Read access is allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction())
        Details: Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 15,4,main] 959836107
        ; dispatch thread: false; isDispatchThread(): false
        SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 1.4#AI-141.2343393, eap:false,6,main] 201131079
```

The exception in generating Android Studio Event Log Window.

Android Studio Version: 1.4.1

Java Version: jdk1.8.0_45

Please tell me how to solve the problem.

Comment: You need to included information like your Java version, AS version, etc

Comment: @Sufian: Please, check my edit